# React-Leaflet: How to clear a Feature Group and add new components using state?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I'm relatively new to react-leaflet and react and am having trouble drawing new components on my map.  I've been stuck for a week now so hoping someone can help.  I'm attempting to clear the components (layers?) from a Feature Group on the map then render new ones by changing the state of a parent component.

In my minimal example program [located at this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-carson-nlsq5?file=/src/Map.jsx) I have a few components:

`Map` parent component which contains states of map, markers, query data, map bounds, and select box value

```
  // state for initial map loading
  let [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  // states in Map component
  let [data, setData] = useState();
  let [bounds, setBounds] = useState(null);
  let [featureNum, setFeatureNum] = useState(1);
  // some random markers simulating user placed markers on map
  let [markers, setMarkers] = useState([
    [27.147144835991796, 31.530761718750004],
    [28.844673680771795, 33.662109375],
    [26.86328062676624, 35.804443359375]
  ]);
```

`Select` which is a dropdown menu that sets the state of `featureNum` when the select box value changes.

`Line` which is a Geojson feature that receives the data from `data` state and sets the state of `markers`. Exists in featuregroup.

`Markers` which creates Marker features using the state of `markers`.  Exists in featuregroup.

After the initial rendering of the map, when the state of `featureNum` changes geojson data is gotten asynchronously via the `fetch` API in my `Map` component.  The bounds of the newly received data are calculated on resolve and the state of `data` and `bounds` are set using the state setters.  The featuregroup is cleared using a useRef hook and `.clearLayers()`

However, no new `Line` component appears on the map when `data` is set.  The map flies to the new bounds where the component should appear.  I tried setting the z-index of the featuregroup to be 9999 but that didn't work either.

**On selecting a feature from the `Select` component,** **how do I clear the map of the featuregroup and show the new `Line` component on the map?** Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this line of code does its job, It clears all layers that belong to the `featureGroup`. On the first render it does not go inside your `if (map)` statement because `map` is `null` but the second time it rerenders when you change the drop down if you log under `setData` call

```
console.log("setData", featureGroupRef.current.getLayers());
```

you will see that layers is an empty `[]`.

So what you should do is first get rid of that line

```
featureGroupRef.current.clearLayers();
```

and then use this [component](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/332#issuecomment-849679887) to be able to both change the data of your GeoJSON as `data` prop is immutable, therefore changing the value won't trigger a rerender and maintain the style you had before.
You will end up with the same code on your Line component but instead of react-leaflet's `GeoJson` component you will use `GeoJsonWithUpdates` of rename it to whatever you think it is more appropriate.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v-3-x-how-to-clear-a-feature-group-and-add-new-components-using-state-pbtrq?file=/src/Map.jsx)